Sporadic poor alternator output
I have a 2011 VW Amarok that’s suffering from sporadic low alternator output. Some days the car will start and will output a solid 13.8-14.4v, other days it’ll only be around 13v.
While 13v is still charging the battery, when it is low it is causing other issues such as flickering dash lights, static through stereo etc. (these mainly occur when depressing the clutch, I assume because the revs drop when the car is put into neutral, slowing the alternator speed further).
When output is low the idle revs also occasionally increase, I assume it’s doing this to try and make up for the voltage drop.
Funny thing is, sometimes when I disconnect and reconnect the battery the problem goes away for a while then returns the next day. My initial assumptions were bad grounds or faulty alternator however I had a new alternator and battery put in but the problem has persisted, I have also check as many ground points as I can find but they all seem to be clean with good connections so I’m completely stumped.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Does your VW use a smart charging system? A battery sensor on one of the battery  cables is one hint of having it. A good battery on standby should show on a multimeter, 12.5vdc, alternator output between 13.5v-14.5v while idling/driving. Smart charging can be deceptive; charging will cease alternator output at any time with a multimeter showing <13 volts, then switch on alternator output, displaying 13.5v-14.5v. There  may be two main grounds; battery to chassis and chassis to engine block. Be sure all cable connections are free of corrosion and secured, disconnect if necessary to examine connections. Main red battery cables  are split to the main engine fuse panel and starter. Check them too.

Thanks for the reply. It doesn’t have a smart charger. I do think there’s a bad connection somewhere, I just haven’t been able to find it yet. The main battery to chassis is all good, however a while ago I checked engine block to chassis and that was full of mud and dirt. At the time I cleaned it and the problem went away for a while, however returned a few weeks later. It’s just strange that sometimes disconnecting and reconnecting the battery seems to temporarily solve the problem. Battery has been tested as is healthy.

A 13yr old vehicle can develop old age issues like intermittent electrical problems so examining main battery wiring on battery and end connections is important to eliminate severe corrosion, especially in regions using salt for winter melt. Salted water simply corrodes metals. You may have to revisit main connections again, disconnecting ends to see if hidden corrosion exists.  A well known youtube repair shop found a severely corroded battery negative cable underneath the Ford pickup, custom made a larger gauge cable to fix the problem. Th dealer failed to find this simple problem.

I'd suggest replacing the voltage regulator, as it seems to be the cheapest first step, considering the alternator has already been replaced.

The new alternator has an internal regulator. That was one of my first thoughts but doesn’t seem to be the issue here
